# Turn laptop windows 7 into wireless hotspot with static IP

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have static IP from my ISP and I want to turn my laptop (windows 7) into wireless through connectify, so I like to ask you if it is possible for static IP? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) is indeed software designed to allow you to turn a laptop into a Wireless Hotspot.  Whether or not your ISP provides you with a Static IP or not is irrelevant.  All you need to use Connectify, is an internet connection... whether that connection includes a Dynamic IP, or a Static IP.

A static IP address would allow you to run something like a web or FTP server, without having to use a Dynamic IP service like No-IP.com in order to be able to connect to it without having to first determine what the IP address has changed to.  It would make using a remote desktop client easier, since you'd always be able to connect to the same static IP address.  It would have no effect on whether or not Connectify would work.

In short, yes.  It is possible.

Comment: http://www.technlg.net/windows/turn-windows-7-computer-wifi-router/ has stepwise documentation